# Using ASP.NET Health Monitoring with MVC 5

Tags: logging, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, health-monitoring

I'm new to ASP.NET Health Monitoring but want to include it in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application (.NET 4.5, VS2013) and can't work out how to use it with the new Universal Providers model.

Any pointers anyone?

Comment: Are you looking to use the entire feature set when it was introduced or just health monitoring?

Comment: Ooh, I'd completely forgotten about this question.  I've changed jobs since I asked it but it would be good to know the answer anyway.  I really needed to be able to monitor an ASP.NET MVC 5 application using external tools.